# Function to make every word possible for array

Tags: c#, arrays

```cs
public void makeWord(string[] array)
        {
            //Give each possible word with the letters in array
            Console.WriteLine("IDK where to start please help");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] array1 = { "S", "I", "R", "E" };

            Hack hacko = new Hack();
            hacko.makeWord(array1);
        }
```

I'm trying to do this code that shows you every possible word with this array, example : "R" "I" "S" "E"